# Load Form in Class Library with pre-defined values C#

Tags: c#, class-library

I'm going to explain this as best I can. I have a form designed into a class library and I make it visible in the middle of the code. When I do this, I want to populate the textboxes with pre-determined values. let's say I want the varaibles color1 and color2 to populate the textboxes. How do I call these variables to when the form loads? None of the textboxes appear in visual studio as I type them...

string color1 = 'blue';
string color2 = 'red';

textbox1.text = color1
textbox2.text = color2

```
InspectionForm myForm = new InspectionForm();
                        myForm.Visible = true;
```

...

```
private void InspectionForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: AFAIK form members are not publicly visible.

Comment: Are you able to change the class library or is it an external resource?

Comment: It's my class library. Is there a better way to go about this? I'm still very new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a constructor on your form

```
public InspectionForm(string color1, string color2)
{
    InitializeComponent(); //This is may or may not be needed
    textBox1.Text = color1;
    textBox2.Text = color2;
}
```

Or make a public method to set your values from.

```
public void SetColors(string color1, string color2)
{
    textBox1.Text = color1;
    textBox2.Text = color2;
}
```

Then use them like so:

```
var form = new InspectionForm("blue", "red");
//or
var form = new InspectionForm();
form.SetColors("blue", "red");
```

However, If you are not able to change the class library, you won't really have any options outside of some reflection hackery.

Comment: sorry for never responding, but this answer helped!